# Can magnetism exist apart from voltage?

Tags: electrical-engineering

A type of electrical amplifier is proposed in which only magnetism and it’s analogous current exists for the most part. There is no voltage and no wattage (to speak of) in which electricity has to noticeably exhibit Ohms Law. Once connections are made to an outside appliance, voltage appears, because none of the junctions in and around the load are shorted with each other nor with ground. But all of the nodes of the power supply section of the circuit are shorted with each other. So there are only two nodes in the power supply, the ground node on one terminal of the sine wave generator and the common node among all of the inductors on the other terminal of the sine wave generator.

Self shorting all of the nodes (in common with each other) eliminates the effectiveness of utilizing any diodes, capacitors, or spark gaps. Only inductors have any relevance in this type of circuit.

Since there is no electrical throughput except through the sine wave generator, mutual inductance has to be precisely tuned. And self inductance also has to be structured a certain way as shown below…

Given a pair of coils (#1), and another pair of coils (#2), and a single coil (#3), and the following magnetic couplings among them:

- Coupling #1 is between coils #1 and coils #2.
- Coupling #2 is between coils #1 and coil #3.
- Coupling #3 is between coils #2 and coil #3.
- Coupling #1 is greater than or equal to the golden ratio of 0.618…
  (e.g. 0.99).
- Coupling #2 is precisely the square root of the difference between unity and coupling #1: $\sqrt{(1 - 0.99)} = \sqrt{(0.01)} = 0.1$, or 10%
- Coupling #3 is precisely the cube of the difference between unity and coupling #1...
  ie, (1 - 0.99)^3 = (0.01)^3 = 0.000001, or 0.0001%.

**What are the chances of effectively replicating super conductance (without altering temperature) by shorting out all of the nodes among all of these five coils and connect this common node to the output of a sine wave generator operating at 1 µV and a frequency of 1 MHz?**

I am assuming that the simulator environment (of a [Micro-Cap circuit](https://ufile.io/ybwqggmj) from Spectrum-Soft) is both theoretical and logical to assume that anything is possible within that environment and limited to that environment with no guarantees outside of that environment making it highly theoretical - not necessarily probable, nor possible - in the concrete world, but only guaranteed in the world of the abstract mathematics involved.

**In the physical world, it’s conjectural to assume it’s probability if coils #1 are made of iron, coils #2 are made of copper, and coil #3 is made of aluminum?**

[image: drawing of circuit diagram]

[image: screenshot of Micro-Cap circuit]

[image: nodal voltages]

[image: first 20 µs of output]

[image: first 10 ms of output]

[image: First 120 ms of output]

Since resistance merely governs voltage drop, any impedance of high resistance will foster our habitual tendency to solve a problem by increasing the voltage. This is known as the Ferranti Effect. On the other hand, a purely reactant impedance can, actually, overcome resistance and begin to exhibit characteristics analogous to superconductivity if the frequency of reactance is high enough to overcome resistance per unit time. Raising the frequency of a sine wave generator does not “cost” more energy. Nor does it defy physics’ conservation of energy. Yet, in this case, amplification of current occurs while voltage retains a zero status within the body of each inductor.

It is not the conservation of energy which is being defied, here. Instead, it is Michael Faraday’s Law of Induction which is given a restraint, a limitation, of jurisdiction. For, it is not always necessary to move a coil through a magnetic field in order to manifest current inside of that coil. Purely reactive impedance, devoid of resistive impedance, is a satisfactory replacement.

Frequency over time is equivalent to motion through space. Magnetic flux, or it’s analog, is rotating in both examples.

The amplitude of a voltage source is not the only option available for supplying an energy input. The frequency of a low voltage source is another, because frequency is a potential form of energy. This is why the conservation of energy has not been defied, because conservation includes both kinetic and potential forms of energy. And Michael Faraday’s Law of Induction has simply been expanded to include a more pervasive definition.

Comment: better answered at the [physics stack](https://physics.stackexchange.com/). Also should be edited to improve clarity.

Comment: @PeteW The Physics stack have already seen it. They kicked it to Electrical Engineering who closed it for being an electrical version of perpetual motion. OP's history shows they are trying it out on various stacks, with different titles.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. Please add a circuit diagram of the machine described above.

Comment: @AJN Added a screenshot of a Micro-Cap circuit simulation example of what I’m describing.

Comment: Ok so you're describing a really hard-to-read description of a resonant circuit made up entirely out of transformers? (is it possible to draw a more conventional circuit diagram??)  What's the question? If the EE folks didn't give you what you want, you're unlikely to find it here :-(

Comment: Your question is just difficult to follow but I do not know if or how it could be improved.

Comment: "*... our habitual tendency to solve a problem by increasing the voltage. This is known as the Ferranti Effect.*" I don't think so. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferranti_effect.

Comment: @PeteW ...shorted transformers. I prefer to call them lumped inductors. I’ll make an attempt to re-draw the schematic. But please keep in mind the electrical connections are not as significant as the mutual inductances.

Comment: @Transistor “The Ferranti effect is more pronounced the longer the line and the higher the voltage applied.”

Answer (score 3):

### Your Conclusions are flawed because they are

> It is not the conservation of energy which is being defied, here.
> Instead, it is Michael Faraday’s Law of Induction which is given a
> restraint, a limitation, of jurisdiction. For, it is not always
> necessary to move a coil through a magnetic field in order to manifest
> current inside of that coil. Purely reactive impedance, devoid of
> resistive impedance, is a satisfactory replacement.

I'm not digging through that wall of text because this conclusion is wrong.

1. No matter how you define it, you can't extract energy from something that doesn't have energy inputs.  Conservation of energy always applies.  Current must have voltage, and changing to AC impedance loads doens't change that.
2. You can't generate current by hooking things up and somehow applying a freqnency.  Reactive impedance is NOT a satisfactory replacement, and if somewhere in the wall of text you've proven it does then that proof is wrong.

Clearly you can have magnetism without current (permanent magnets), but your derivation of current without motion or magnetism is prima facie wrong.  This is perpetual motion and will certainly never fly in this ME-heavy SE, which understands the Second Law very well.

> because frequency is a potential form of energy.

No, it isn't.  A wave/particle with a frequency has energy, frequency on its own isn't a thing.